# Why aren't the html buttons working in chrome/microsoft edge?

Tags: html, css

I just wrote a random webpage of a calculator in which there are a LOT of buttons but some of them aren't working I dunno why.

CSS and HTML code attached below.
"By not working" I mean whenever I click on them there is no response, as if they are just buttons. I mean I haven't yet linked them to any JS functions, but just like when you click on a button of a TV remote, the button appears to move down and when you release the pressure, it appears to move up.

Similarly when I click the functions' buttons, the "moving" effect is observed but when I click the numbers' button, there is not effect seen.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #F1C7C7;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
              }


.doggy {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
     /*position:absolute; bottom:50px; right:688px;*/
}
.doggy1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
    
}
.doggy2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
    
}
.doggy3 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
    
}
.doggy4 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy4 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy5 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy6 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy7 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy8 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;

}

.vertical { 
            border-left: 15px solid black; 
            height: 300px; 
            position:absolute;
             bottom:173.3px; 
             left : 687.5px;
             
             /*margin:auto;*/

        } 
.dad {
    background-color: #D7F3F3;
    height: 100px;
    width: 450px;
    border-radius: 20%;
    margin: auto;

}



.doggy9 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 275px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;

}
.doggy10 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;

}
.doggy11 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 275px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 23.3px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;

}
.doggy12 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 275px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;

}
.doggy13 {
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:220px; 
    left:428px;

}
.doggy14 {
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:287.66666px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy15 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:362px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy16 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:428px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy17 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:361.555px; 
    left:470px;

}
.doggy18 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:428px; 
    left:470px;

}
.doggy19 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:212.222222px; 
    left:479px;

}
.doggy20 {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:360px; 
    left:484px;

}
.doggy21 {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:285px; 
    left:475px;

}
.doggy22 {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:415px; 
    left:485px;

}
.doggy23 {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:215px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy24 {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:292.5px; 
    left:422.55px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Calculator.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a Calculator!!!</h1>
    <div class = "rectangle">
        
            

        
        <form>
            <div class = "dad">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            

            <input type="button" id="abcd" value="1" class = "doggy">

            <input type="button" id="abcd1" value="2" class = "doggy1">
            <input type="button" id="abcd2" value="3" class = "doggy2">
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd3" value="4" class = "doggy3">
            <input type="button" id="abcd4" value="5" class = "doggy4">
            <input type="button" id="abcd5" value="6" class = "doggy5">
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd6" value="7" class = "doggy6">
            <input type="button" id="abcd7" value="8" class = "doggy7">
            <input type="button" id="abcd8" value="9" class = "doggy8">
            <div class = "vertical">
            </div></div>
            <input type="button" id="abcd9" value="+" class = "doggy9"><input type="button" id="abcd13" value=  &#x221a; class = "doggy13"> <!--Square root--> 
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd10" value="-" class = "doggy10"><input type="button" id="abcd14" value=&#x221B; class = "doggy14"><!--Cube Root-->
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd11" value=&#xd7; class = "doggy11"><!--Multiplication--><input type="button" id="abcd15" value="sin(x)"; class = "doggy15">
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd12" value=&#xf7; class = "doggy12"><!--Division--><input type="button" id="abcd16" value="cos(x)" class = "doggy16">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy17" id = "abcd17" value = "arcsin(x)">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy18" id = "abcd18" value = "arccos(x)">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy19" id = "abcd19" value = "n!">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy20" id = "abcd20" value = "ln(n)">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy21" id = "abcd21" value = "1/x">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy22" id = "abcd22" value = "%">
            <button class = "doggy23" id = "abcd23">a<sup>x</sup></button>
            <button class = "doggy24" id = "abcd24">log<sub>a</sub>x</button>
        </form>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the container div("dad") css class height is set to 100px.
Remove it and it should work.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #F1C7C7;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
              }


.doggy {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
     /*position:absolute; bottom:50px; right:688px;*/
}
.doggy1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
    
}
.doggy2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
    
}
.doggy3 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
    
}
.doggy4 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy4 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy5 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy6 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy7 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;
}
.doggy8 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: : 15px;

}

.vertical { 
            border-left: 15px solid black; 
            height: 300px; 
            position:absolute;
             bottom:173.3px; 
             left : 687.5px;
             
             /*margin:auto;*/

        } 
.dad {
    background-color: #D7F3F3;
    
    width: 450px;
    border-radius: 20%;
    margin: auto;

}



.doggy9 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 275px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;

}
.doggy10 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;

}
.doggy11 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 275px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 23.3px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;

}
.doggy12 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 275px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;

}
.doggy13 {
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:220px; 
    left:428px;

}
.doggy14 {
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 28%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:287.66666px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy15 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:362px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy16 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:428px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy17 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:361.555px; 
    left:470px;

}
.doggy18 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:428px; 
    left:470px;

}
.doggy19 {
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:212.222222px; 
    left:479px;

}
.doggy20 {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:360px; 
    left:484px;

}
.doggy21 {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:285px; 
    left:475px;

}
.doggy22 {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:415px; 
    left:485px;

}
.doggy23 {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:215px; 
    left:425px;

}
.doggy24 {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right:  15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom:  9px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:292.5px; 
    left:422.55px;

}
```

```html
    <h1>This is a Calculator!!!</h1>
    <div class = "rectangle">
        
            

        
        <form>
            <div class = "dad">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            

            <input type="button" id="abcd" value="1" class = "doggy">

            <input type="button" id="abcd1" value="2" class = "doggy1">
            <input type="button" id="abcd2" value="3" class = "doggy2">
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd3" value="4" class = "doggy3">
            <input type="button" id="abcd4" value="5" class = "doggy4">
            <input type="button" id="abcd5" value="6" class = "doggy5">
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd6" value="7" class = "doggy6">
            <input type="button" id="abcd7" value="8" class = "doggy7">
            <input type="button" id="abcd8" value="9" class = "doggy8">
            <div class = "vertical">
            </div></div>
            <input type="button" id="abcd9" value="+" class = "doggy9"><input type="button" id="abcd13" value=  &#x221a; class = "doggy13"> <!--Square root--> 
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd10" value="-" class = "doggy10"><input type="button" id="abcd14" value=&#x221B; class = "doggy14"><!--Cube Root-->
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd11" value=&#xd7; class = "doggy11"><!--Multiplication--><input type="button" id="abcd15" value="sin(x)"; class = "doggy15">
            </br>
            <input type="button" id="abcd12" value=&#xf7; class = "doggy12"><!--Division--><input type="button" id="abcd16" value="cos(x)" class = "doggy16">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy17" id = "abcd17" value = "arcsin(x)">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy18" id = "abcd18" value = "arccos(x)">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy19" id = "abcd19" value = "n!">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy20" id = "abcd20" value = "ln(n)">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy21" id = "abcd21" value = "1/x">
            <input type="button" class = "doggy22" id = "abcd22" value = "%">
            <button class = "doggy23" id = "abcd23">a<sup>x</sup></button>
            <button class = "doggy24" id = "abcd24">log<sub>a</sub>x</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```